# Push Notification for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using MPNS to push notifications to my windows phone app. Messages are being delivered properly and i can see and open my app using the toast.

The issue i am facing is that many a times, the text in the message comes as "New Notification". Has anyone else faced this issue. Kindly help

Comment: This is not a solution to your question but can you suggest me on how to implement mpns notification in windows phone app? Any link or source?

Comment: I have not seen this.  The only way I can think of this happening is if you are sending the text "New Notification".  Search all your source code doing the push for this string.